# Controlling slideshow speed with a slider

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to create an automatic slideshow that I place inside of a canvas, and that I can control the speed of the slideshow with a slider. Before I even think about the canvas, I want to focus on the slider.

How can I make my slider work with my slideshow, so that I can control the speed, between 1 second and 5 second delay?

[This is my code.](https://jsfiddle.net/em2hvcqd/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
* {box-sizing: border-box;}
body {
        font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
}
.mySlides {
        display: none;
}

img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}

/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

.dot {
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active {
  background-color: #717171;
}

/* Fading animation */
.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

</style>
</head>
<body>


<div class="slideshow-container">

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <img src="1.png" style="width:100%">
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <img src="2.png" style="width:100%">
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <img src="3.png" style="width:100%">
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <img src="4.png" style="width:100%">
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <img src="5.png" style="width:100%">
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <img src="6.png" style="width:100%">
</div>
</div>

<div style="text-align:center">
  <span class="dot"></span> 
  <span class="dot"></span> 
  <span class="dot"></span> 
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
</div>

<div style="text-align:right">  
    <input id="speed" name="speed" type="range" min="1" max="5" value="3">
    <p style="color: black">Value: <span id="speedValue"></span></p>        
        <script>
            var slider = document.getElementById("speed");
            var output = document.getElementById("speedValue");
            output.innerHTML = slider.value;// Display the default slider value
            // Update the current slider value (each time you drag the slider handle)
            slider.oninput = function() {
            output.innerHTML = this.value;
            }
        </script>
</div>

<script>
var slideIndex = 0;
showSlides();

function showSlides() {
    var i;
    var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
       slides[i].style.display = "none";  
    }
    slideIndex++;
    if (slideIndex > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
    for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
        dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
    dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
    setTimeout(showSlides, 2000); 
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have to explain a lot more than you have in your question for us to help you. There may be too many factors here making this too broad. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

You are close to this already, you just need to make the `setTimeout` in your `showSlides()` func to be based off of the value from your slider.

Here is how I did it in your JSFiddle:

**SpeedMod Variable**

```
var speedMod = 3
```

Create a new global var, I called mine `speedMod` but you can name it anything. I also defaulted the value to `3` because that is what your slider default was, but you can change this as well.

**slider.oninput = function()**

Now we want to add the code to modify our global var when the slider changes. In your `slider.oninput = function()` add the following line `speedMod = this.value;`. Your whole function will look like this:

```
slider.oninput = function() {
            output.innerHTML = this.value;
            speedMod = this.value;
}
```

**showSlides function**

Last piece is to make our timeout based off of our `speedMod` value. This can be accomplished by replacing:

```
setTimeout(showSlides, 2000);
```

with

```
setTimeout(showSlides, speedMod*1000);
```

Remember to include the `*1000` because `setTimeout()` works in ms, not full seconds.

Let me know if you need any more help.

[Full JSFiddle with changes](https://jsfiddle.net/ntjnxum0/)

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much!!! Question: Would it be difficult to place this slideshow in a canvas, now that I have done it?

Comment: Can't say I know much about canvas (haven't used/heard of it before). Maybe give it a go and if you get stuck open up a new SO question and someone will help ya - good luck